# How to fix/customise coloring for the autocompletion popup menu?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, autocompletion, colorscheme, plugin-you-complete-me, popup-menu

I'm not really happy with the syntax coloring of the auto-completion menu.

Probably the pink-ish background color is the least unpleasant thing, but the grey foreground text is really not as readable on that pink as plain black would be; then the background for some characters is grey or blue-ish.

In fact, it seems that the text uses the syntax coloring of the language, which I don't think is very useful, because it seems to be not aware at all of the pink background.

Has anyone found a good set of settings to get a better user experience with this?

One more though, I think I'd rather have the current argument (`{expr}` in the image below) highlighted not by means of a foreground/background color combo, but by italic or bold text, for instance.

[image]

Comment: They use the hilight groups PMenu and PMenuSel. Override those and you change the completion popups look. Course, if you use different themes but a single override things may not always look so great. But anything's better than that horrible pink which is the default PMenu value

Comment: To change something _within_ like your example with `expr` I guess you'll need to redefine how the groups are activated (via matching rules)...which is a little more involved than just changing some colors. I have a plugin that uses new popups and they rely on PMenu/PMenuSel so I've pondered something similar (though they can be superseded by Popup and PopupSelected groups so there's more flexibility there...assuming legacy/completion popups don't use those groups....which I'd need to verify).